# How to configure apache solr with existing spring mvc 4 hibernate 4 application?

Tags: solr, tomcat7, solrj

How to configure and run apache solr with spring mvc in tomcat7 server? Will apache solr run only by specifying dependency in maven or do I have to install apache solr in local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have **Solr service running** in your system or in any server instance, only then you will be able to connect and do some operation on Solr.

Specifying dependency in maven will be useful only to get connected to Solr and do read/write operation on Solr service.

For instance if we compare this with any database system, then your database server is running some where and you use any jdbc driver in your application to perform CRUD operation on that RDBMS.

You can follow the below steps to install and run Solr

1. Make sure you have installed Java
2. Download Solr from http://lucene.apache.org/solr/
3. Extract Solr distribution archive to a directory
4. Start Solr server by issuing following command:

   ```
   -- if you are in linux distribution then 
   $ bin/solr start

   -- if you are in windows then
   bin\solr.cmd start
   ```
5. Once Solr server is running, use a Web browser to see the Admin Console at http://localhost:8983/solr/

For more detailed instructions follow these links

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Installing+Solr
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr

Comment: I have installed appache solr 6 how do I connect it with my spring mvc application

Comment: you need to use Spring Data Solr check the links http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-solr/ http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-data-solr-tutorial/

Comment: The above url does not show how to to connect solr to MySQL database.I would like to know whether i should go forward with apache solr or hibernate search as i have to perorm search with data related to database.which one would you recommend as most of my data is in object and not in xml?

Comment: i think you should post a new question instead of updating existing with new question. Rolling back to your initial question.

Comment: @PrasadKhode you could have kept the spelling fix from the title. ;)